# Sites like lang-8, but for handwriting

Tags: discussion, resources

Are there any sites that are like lang-8.com, but allow reviewing of hand-writing?

Is it socially acceptable to post hand-writing to lang-8 itself?

Comment: You should tip the lan-8 team with this idea, they might try to implement it :-) It would do a fun smartphone app, using either camera or finger-drawing, probably for single words rather than long essays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any site specifically tailored to reviewing handwriting. I think there would be no problem posting a picture of handwriting on lang-8, but you may get fewer corrections because it would be more annoying to correct. (This would be the case on any website of course, since it involves pictures to show the handwriting.)